# Open accordion tabs with named anchors

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui, anchor, jquery-ui-accordion

I'm using the jQueryUI accordion widget in one site:

```
<ul id="accordion">
    <li id="tab1">
        <h2>title 1</h2>
        <div>text 1</p></div>
    </li>
    <li id="tab2">
        <h2>title 2</h2>
        <div>text 2</p></div>
    </li>
    <li id="tab3">
        <h2>title 3</h2>
        <div>text 3</p></div>
    </li>

    ....

</ul>


$('#accordion').accordion({
    heightStyle: 'content',
    animate: 100,
    collapsible: true,
});
```

I know you can open one particular tab using the active property and a zero-based index. I'm wondering if it's possible to open a tab specifying a named anchor? Something like:

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
    heightStyle: 'content',
    animate: 100,
    collapsible: true,
    active: 'tab2'
});
```

I'd like the accordion to open from an outside link, like this:

```
www.domain.com/page/#tab2
```

Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
jQuery(function() {
    jQuery( "#work" ).accordion({
    collapsible: true,
    active: "h3#id"
    });
});
```

From here: [Jquery Accordion, Set Active by ID](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13165529/jquery-accordion-set-active-by-id)

Comment: Here you are using H2. Replace H3 to H2

Comment: Apparently, this worked in jQuery UI 1.9 but no longer works in 1.10 (the version I'm using). I found a solution that works here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175515/jqueryui-accordion-setting-active-using-id

Answer (score 0):

### [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/tTh2B/)

To normally active the tab, use this,

```
$('#accordion').accordion({
    heightStyle: 'content',
    animate: 100,
    collapsible: true,
    active: '#tab2 h2'
});
```

---

For your requirement , Try this working snippet.

```
var url = window.location.href;

var tab = url.substr(url.lastIndexOf('/')+1);

$('#accordion').accordion({
    heightStyle: 'content',
    animate: 100,
    collapsible: true,
    active: tab+ ' h2'
});
```

You can set accordion as active using `active : 'selector'`. Here the selector is h2 - child of li with Id -tab2

Comment: Apparently, the `active : 'selector'` part worked in jQuery UI 1.9 but no longer works in 1.10 (the version I'm using). I found a solution that works here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22175515/jqueryui-accordion-setting-active-using-id